# in app purchase is failing to validate receipts from google play

Tags: node.js, google-play, in-app-purchase

I have followed this tutorial in setting up my in-app-purchase process.  My code have been working until today when I started receiving this error:

[Error: invalid_grant]

When trying to validate the receipt from google.  I have set up the following details in my config:

```
iap.config({ 
    googlePublicKeyStrSandBox: googlePublicKeyStrSandBox, 
    googlePublicKeyStrLive: googlePublicKeyStrLive,
    googleAccToken: googleAccToken,
    googleRefToken: googleRefToken,
    googleClientID: googleClientID,
    googleClientSecret: googleClientSecret
});
```

I tried adding some code to refresh the google token as follows:

```
iap.setup((err) => {
    if (err) {
        full = { messageText: 'Failed: Invalid In-app purchase set up', category:'ProcessSubscriptionGoogle'}
        callback(null, full);
    } else {
        // refresh token before validating the receipt
        iap.refreshGoogleToken( function (err, response) {
            if (err) {
                full = { messageText: 'Failed: Cannot Refresh Token', category:'ProcessSubscriptionGoogle'}
                callback(null, full);
            } else {
                iap.validate(validationType, googleReceipt, (err, response) => {
                    if (err) {
                        full = { messageText: 'Failed: Invalid Receipt', category:'ProcessSubscriptionGoogle'}
                        callback(null, full);
                    } else {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
            }
        })            
  }
});
```

But I'm still having the same invalid_grant error.  Am I doing the refresh correctly?  Should I even include the refresh in my code?

Comment: i may have found the problem but don't know how to fix it yet.  When I was trying to debug a problem in the in app purchase, i removed my app from the list of application that has been granted access to my google developer account from the sign-in and security screen of my google account.